# Jupyter notebook and/or anaconda taking up storage

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, storage

I've been working (on a Windows machine) in a Jupyter notebook, using Anaconda, and have run some lines of code that froze my computer temporarily while they were executing - specifically, using pandas.read_parquet to read a >3GB parquet file as a DataFrame.

Then, I noticed that the storage on my computer decreased from ~20GB free to ~15MB free, and I started getting low disk space notifications.

I restarted my computer and my storage is back up to ~16GB free. What's going on? (I don't really know much about computers.) And is there a way I can prevent this from happening, limit Jupyter's memory/storage access, etc?

EDIT: I realized that this occurs when I run the command

```py
df = pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet')
```

and filename.parquet is only 17MB. However it does have 200,000 rows and 5160 columns.